# Set up sbt to fetch dependency for another version of Scala than the project's?

Tags: sbt

My project uses Scala `2.9.3`, and I want to use [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire) for `2.9.2`. What do I specify in my sbt build file to get Spire for 2.9.2?

I tried

```
"org.spire-math" %% "spire" % "0.6.0"
```

but it fails looking for Scala 2.9.3.

Comment: What version of sbt are you using?

Answer (score 2):

- One has to append the corresponding library name with an underscore and required scala version and verify the appropriate version number of the library(in my case, 0.3.0)

  "org.spire-math" % "spire_2.9.2" % "0.3.0"

Comment: `%%` appends the Scala version number, so if you are manually appending it yourself already as in your example, then you want just `%` not `%%`.